# How to get Response before mapping to model using Retrofit 2.0.2 Android

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

I am having a problem using retrofit library While getting response i want to check response code before mapping to my class

Comment: `response.code()`

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose You can add

```
if(response.isSuccessful) {
//do something
} else {
// do something
}
```

**response.isSuccessful()** returns you a boolean value if the code is in the range (200..300)

Comment: Sir Thanks for Reply I have multiple JsonArrays Inside main array i want to check whether array contains data or empty

Comment: You asked response code in your question.  Without parsing, how are you going to check if you have data in your array?